# ReSharper 9 "File Layout / Type Member Layout" without regions

Tags: c#, resharper

I switched from R# 8 to R# 9. When I import my type members layout and then choose ReSharper -> Tools -> Cleanup Code... it will apply the ordering but no regions are visible. It simply reorders the items. So, how can I get my regions back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. You have to use the designer and drag the region explicitely into your area like this:

[image: Use regions]

Comment: Having done this many times and it never working I did find a {missing} step that made it work.  JUST dragging in a region and dropping the constructors block in without doing anything else doesn't get it done. IN their designer hit the Load.. button then load the Default With Regions option.  Then add any addition blocks you want regioned.  I think it helps if you make sure to give the region a name.  I suspect that if you don't go into the properties and set the sort/group options that not everything needed is being added to the XML.